# How to spread object values into itself in EF Core Select()?

Tags: entity-framework-core

In my project, that uses EF Core 6, I have an entity that looks like this:

```cs
public class Animal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    // ... many other fields that exist in the database

    virtual public bool IsRelatedToGoldenCity { get; set; }
}
```

With `IsRelatedToGoldenAnimal` being a value that will be calculated in a sub-query. Since there are many fields in this class, I would like to not have to write all them down in the select where the sub-query will happen. Something like:

```cs
var query = Context.Animal
    .Include(x => x.Whatever)
    .Select(x => new Animal
    {
        ...x, // mimicking JavaScript's spread operator here
        IsRelatedToGoldenCity = Context.Cities.Select(...).Where(...).Any(),
    });

return await query.ToListAsync();
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: *I would like to not have to write all them down in the select*. Sadly but you should repeat assignment for all fields.

Comment: I don't know if EFCore will let you do this, but you can try:

```Context.Animal.Include(x => x.whatever).Select(x => { x.IsRelatedToGoldenCity = /* other query */;

    return x;
})```

Comment: @peter VSCode gave me an error right away saying I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `ToList` and `ForEach`

```
var animals = await Context.Animal
    .Include(x => x.Whatever)
     .ToListAsync();

animals.ForEach(x => x.IsRelatedToGoldenCity = "");
```

Comment: `x.IsRelatedToGoldenCity` is calculated with a subquery, so I can't really do it after the ToListAsync, for performance reasons. I can't do them simultaneously either, because of how transactions have been implemented in the project.